# PHP submit an form only if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form with a check box and an input text. Here is my form:

```html
<form action="index.php?option=com_platiniumchristmas&view=success" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsConditions" id="chbx" value="Yes" onclick="foo()" />
    <?php echo JText::_( 'COM_PLATINIUMCHRISTMAS_TERMSCONDITIONS_TEXT');?>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Emitir Voucher" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right" />
  <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
    <input type="text" name="friendName" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="canal" value="<?php echo $_POST[" canal "]; ?>"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

The idea is only to submit the form if the checked box value is checked. How can I go about this. I have tried using javascript but no success.

The javascript I tried to Use:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");
 function foo(){
   if(checkbox.checked){
     alert("meap");
  };
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript at all. Just use the `required` attribute for the [constraint validation API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/).

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_platiniumchristmas&view=success" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsConditions" id="chbx" value="Yes" required />
    <?php echo JText::_( 'COM_PLATINIUMCHRISTMAS_TERMSCONDITIONS_TEXT');?>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Emitir Voucher" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right" />
  <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
    <input type="text" name="friendName" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="canal" value="<?php echo $_POST[" canal "]; ?>"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

This will stop the form from submitting unless the checkbox is checked. Do remember, you still need backend validation as always to verify since requests can be forged if enough effort is put into it.

Answer (score 0):

try complete example, it should work.

and then correct your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script> function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    } } </script> </head> <body>

<form name="myForm" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>

</body> </html>
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Yes if it is possible your help I will be tank full. Javascript I new using this language

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        alert("Please select the checkbox.");

        //stop the form from submitting
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

<form id='form'>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
   </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Do thing" >
    </div>
</form>
```

use this

Answer (score -1):

You lose the context in your code. try:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

 function foo(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");
   if(checkbox.checked){
     alert("meap");
  };
 };
</script>
```